# DNU Restore results in multiple "The file exists" warning and errors and eventually dies

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, dnu, dnvm

I recently updated my VS 2015 to Update 2 and also did a dnvm update-self.  After taking these actions I'm now unable to perform dnu restores. I see the following error for almost every package from both myget and nuget

```
     GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit.runner.dnx'
Warning: FindPackagesById: xunit.runner.dnx
  The file exists.

  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit.runner.dnx'
Error: FindPackagesById: xunit.runner.dnx
  The file exists.
```

Eventually the entire operation bombs out.  I've tried reinstalling my DNX's (currently using RC1-Update1), deleting all packages etc... to no avail.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found what resolved my issue here:

https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2505

Looks like my %userprofile%/AppData/Local/Temp folder got some possibly corrupted data in it that was confusing dnu restore. DNU restore caches packages here during processing. I purged the directory and DNU restore appears to be working well again.